# Why can't convert DateTime to String when concat

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Why when using datetime as a stand alone mssql can cast it. But when concat to a string it can't?

```
declare @foo datetime
set @foo = '2015-10-10'
--Works
print @foo
--Doesn't work
print 'my foo' + @foo
```

Comment: You need to cast it as varchar when concatening and using a print statement as the type isn't a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `+` can mean either addition or string concatenation.  So, convert it explicitly to a string:

```
'my foo' + convert(varchar(12), @foo, 120)
```

Comment: so it is possible to add something to datetime by using +?